# useSelector property returns undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, frontend

I'm trying to fetch 'all posts' using Redux. I should be getting an empty array but instead, I'm getting undefined. Here's my reducer:

```
export default (posts = [], action) => {
  switch ((action.type)) {
    case "FETCH_ALL":
      return action.payload;
    case "CREATE":
      return posts;

    default:
      return posts;
  }
};
```

Action

```
export const getPosts = () => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    const { data } = await api.fetchPosts();
    dispatch({ type: "FETCH_ALL", payload: data });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message)
  }
};
```

Posts.js component

```
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import Post from "./Post/Post";
import useStyles from "./styles";

const Posts = () => {
  const posts = useSelector((state)=>state.posts)
  console.log(posts)
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <>
      <h1>Posts</h1>
      <Post />
    </>
  );
};

export default Posts;
```

Comment: Can you also show us your store file and Combine reducers, if that's a different file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to your reducer, your entire state is a posts array instead of a state object like { posts: [ ] }. So in your selector, you can simply return the state as it is in the Posts component.

```
 const posts = useSelector((state)=>state);
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you need to change a line in your reducer file. You need to assign the action.payload to the posts and then you can access it

```
export default (posts = [], action) => {
  switch ((action.type)) {
    case "FETCH_ALL":
      return {posts: action.payload};
    case "CREATE":
      return posts;

    default:
      return posts;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Firstly, `switch ((action.type))` should be `switch (action.type)`
2. Then, you should check the `data` from api whether it's returned
   correctly or not
3. Finally, check your redux state object and your selector of `posts`